# VBA for data validation

Tags: vba, excel

Recently, I found a code on a book for data validation, which is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = “$A$1” Then
    If Not IsNumeric(Target) Then
    MsgBox “Enter a number in cell A1.”
    Range(“A1”).ClearContents
    Range(“A1”).Activate
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

I would like to change it to validate my custom format in column A which is XY & 6 number (XY123456) and modified the code. But the MsgBox will pop up continuously and I cannot close it when the format is wrong. Could someone give me some advice. Thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 1 Then
    If Left(Target.Value, 2) <> "XY" Or 
       Not IsNumeric(Right(Target.Value,6)) Or 
       Len(Target.Value) <> 8  Then
    MsgBox “Wrong Format”
    Target.ClearContents
    Target.Activate
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo EH

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Left(Target.Value, 2) <> "XY" Or Not IsNumeric(Right(Target.Value, 6)) Or Len(Target.Value) <> 8 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            MsgBox "Wrong Format"
            Target.ClearContents
            Target.Activate
        End If
    End If

EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

You need to turn off events otherwise `Target.ClearContents` will trigger the event again and again until you run out of stack space. In order to make it a little bit more bullet proof I also added an error handler to make sure the event handler gets turned on again in case of an error.

Comment: Hi Storax, as I am a beginner to VBA, may I know why the original code from book can work properly without "Application.EnableEvents =" however it doesn't work in my code. Thanks

Comment: The original is also faulty but it only runs twice because the second time `IsNumeric(Target)` is true as target is empty.

Comment: Good catch on the enableevents but this will error if target is more than a single cell. Also, what happens if a value is cleared?

Comment: And I would like to ask one stupid question that if there is no error, will EH be executed? If not, the Application.EnableEvents will be False all the time?

Comment: @Jeeped, , do you mean that if i copy a range of data into column A?

Comment: @Jeeped: You are right, to make it really clean code you also have to check how many cells have been selected. But as I do not know  the needs of the OP that has to be left to him, IMHO.

Comment: @K Ng: EnableEvents will always run as I did not put an `Exit Sub` before it. For an introduction to error handling have a look [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/).

Comment: @Storax, Thank you very much.