# Excel VB Function too many time

Tags: excel, vba, function, call

I am new writing VB function. I have one function to display message.
and I have sub, which call these function.

```
   Function refreshSheetData()
      MsgBox "Function call..."
   End Function

   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      If (Target.Address = "$B$3") Then
          refreshSheetData
      End If
   End Sub
```

When changed value in cell B3, it run these to display message many time. I have to click OK on message popup many time before it closed.
Is there any way I can stop call this function many time.

thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this but have you tried switching off events inside the worksheet sheet change before the If and then back on after? Does B3 contain a formula?

Comment: Side note, functions should return a value. If you don't need a value returned by it, you should be using a Sub instead (i.e., `Sub refreshSheetData()`).

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126572/vba-for-data-validation/52126599#52126599)

Comment: Where do you use refreshSheetData() function?

Answer (score 1):

As said turn off Events

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      On Error goto EH
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      If (Target.Address = "$B$3") Then
          refreshSheetData
      End If
   EH:
      Application.EnableEvents = True
   End Sub
```